# crontab script fail: end of file unexpected (expecting ")") when call $(date)

Tags: bash, cron, goaccess

I want to add

```
0 5 1 * * goaccess -f /var/log/nginx/access.log -a > /home/xan/reports/report-week-$(date +%Y.%m.%d).html
```

but crontab always complains about that:

```
Subject: Cron <root@deimos> goaccess -f /var/log/nginx/access.log -a > /home/xan/reports/report-week-$(date +
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <E1bIogT-0001FX-9n@deimos>
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2016 05:00:01 +0200

/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

What the proper syntax to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`%` has special meaning in a crontab (it represents a newline), so you need to escape it to specify a literal percent sign.

```
 0 5 1 * * goaccess ... > /home/xan/reports/report-week-$(date +\%Y.\%m.\%d).html
```

Comment: Which crons does this work on? My crontab page says you have to use `\%`

Comment: Apparently the one in my imagination, the one that resembles `printf`.

Comment: @chepter: Thanks. Can you give me the reference of which % is special sign in cron?

Comment: On my system Ubuntu with timezone PKT; date show %b (i.e. locale's abbreviated month name) in Urdu. Any suggestion how to show it in English.